# a fair coins is tossed until head $3$ times. what is the probability to get head on the first toss given that we tossed it 6 times?

Tags: probability

so I Tried playing with the formula of Conditional probability and some variations of combinatorics, because i know for sure that the 6th toss was head (we stop on the 3rd time we get head, and it's given to us that we stopped after 6 tosses).
I know the answer is 0.4, but I cant unserstand how to get this answer...
any help please?

Comment: Hint:  you know that exactly $3$ out of the $6$ tosses were $H$, and that the last toss was an $H$.  Thus exactly $2$ out of the first $5$ tosses were $H$ so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, with combinatorics alone:

1) following lulu's hint that 2 of the remaining 5 are heads we get that the number of ways of selecting two regardless of ordering is 5*4/2=10.

2) if we fix one of those as 1, there are 4 possibilities 4/10= 0.4